# Importing Data Google Sheet to Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

Sorry for all the nooby questions.

I have 2 spreadsheets:

- 1 contains all names and pay rates
- Another is a timesheet format

I basically need a formula on the timesheet spreadsheet that will look at the payrate spreadsheet and import the data across.

Example:

- Name Spreadsheet - (A1) Beth Hawkins (B1) £120
- Timesheet Spreadsheet - the name Beth Hawkins is inputted into cell C9, I need a formula in cell O9 to then go into the name spreadsheet and find the payrate that Beth is on, and automatically input that when the name is typed

Is this even possible?

Thanks again!!!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned

> Name Spreadsheet - `(A1)` Beth Hawkins `(B1)` £120
>
> Timesheet Spreadsheet - the name Beth Hawkins is inputted into cell
> `C9`, I need a formula in cell `O9` to then go into the name
> spreadsheet and find the payrate that Beth is on, and automatically
> input that when the name is typed

You can use the following formula in cell `O9`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C9,IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxx","Name!A1:B"),2,0))
```

*(where `xxxxxxx` is the Name Spreadsheet ID)*

Functions used:

- [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)